# Node Crypto diffieHellman.setPrivateKey()

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, public-key-encryption, node-crypto

I have been using the Crypto lib in Node for doing Pub Key exchange.  So far I have just been using `.getDiffieHellman('modp5')` generate a new public / private key for each new connection.  This methodology works great for computing a secret for use with AES encryption.

However, I would like to be able to save a Private Key into a file, and then Load it upon next execution.  It seems like the way to do this would be `.getPrivateKey()` and then `.setPrivateKey()` but using `.setPrivateKey()` on a `crypto.createDiffieHellman` class generated by `.getDiffieHellman('modp5')` does not work.  This is actually stated in the documentation:

> The returned object mimics the interface of objects created by crypto.createDiffieHellman() above, but will not allow to change the keys (with diffieHellman.setPublicKey() for example).

Knowing this, if I have generated a Private Key using the following code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var Key = crypto.getDiffieHellman('modp5');
Key.generateKeys();
var PrvKey = Key.getPrivateKey();
save_to_file(PrvKey);
```

How do I go about loading that same Private Key at a later date?

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var PrvKey = load_from_file();
var Key = crypto.createDiffieHellman(prime, [encoding]);
Key.setPrivateKey( PrvKey )
```

I looked at the [RFC2412](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412.txt) that was specified in the crypto documentation and found that the prime for group 5 is listed as:

> 2^1536 - 2^1472 - 1 + 2^64 * { [2^1406 pi] +  741804}
>
> 241031242692103258855207602219756607485695054850245994265411
>   694195810883168261222889009385826134161467322714147790401219
>   650364895705058263194273070680500922306273474534107340669624
>   601458936165977404102716924945320037872943417032584377865919
>   814376319377685986952408894019557734611984354530154704374720
>   774996976375008430892633929555996888245787241299381012913029
>   459299994792636526405928464720973038494721168143446471443848
>   8520940127459844288859336526896320919633919
>
> FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC90FDAA22168C234C4C6628B80DC1CD1
>   29024E088A67CC74020BBEA63B139B22514A08798E3404DD
>   EF9519B3CD3A431B302B0A6DF25F14374FE1356D6D51C245
>   E485B576625E7EC6F44C42E9A637ED6B0BFF5CB6F406B7ED
>   EE386BFB5A899FA5AE9F24117C4B1FE649286651ECE45B3D
>   C2007CB8A163BF0598DA48361C55D39A69163FA8FD24CF5F
>   83655D23DCA3AD961C62F356208552BB9ED529077096966D
>   670C354E4ABC9804F1746C08CA237327FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

I attempted to take this prime and put it into `.createDiffieHellman(prime, [encoding])`.  However, after doing so, `.setPrivateKey()` complained about an incorrect key length.

Any insight would be appreciated.